# RSA encryption - How to encrypt to smaller size than key

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I use RSA encryption in my project, and I need to encrypt array of bytes to encrypted array of bytes, that his length is smaller than the key length (I use 2048 bit key).
When I use the RSACryptoServiceProvider class with c# it always encrypt it to an array of bytes that his length is the key length (256 bytes).
I know I cannot encrypt it to a longer size than the key, but, can I encrypt it to a smaller one (to the originial non-encrypted array of bytes length)?

Answer (score 5):

No. Padding the plaintext up to the key size before encryption is necessary to protect against certain types of cryptanalytic attacks, so it does not make sense for an RSA implementation (*especially* those intended for general use) to omit it.

Comment: And modular exponentiation will otherwise make sure that even relatively small input will result in a ciphertext that is about the same size as the modulus.